# cplex java api modelling 1-sum_j 2d array

Tags: java, cplex

I have tried modelling the expression `Sum_j (1-(Sum_i z[i][j])) * c[i][j]`, where `z[i][j]` are my boolean variables of the obj function. I tried this by modelling as an expression every column of the array and then an expression for 1-sum of  collumns and so forth. Something like `sum(prod(sum(1,negative(sum_j)),c[ij]))`. But didn't make it. I would like a little help. Thanks

[edit]My objective function would be "Sum_i Sum_j c[ij]*z[ij]  +   Sum_j (1-(Sum_i z[i][j])) * uc[j]" , where z(ij) are the decision variables and the others are known. My problem is that i am trying to decompose the expression into smaller subexpressions. So afterwards i want to somehow merge them.

```
            IloNumExpr[] colexpr = new IloLinearNumExpr[commuters];
            IloNumExpr[] colexpr2 = new IloLinearNumExpr[commuters];
            IloNumExpr[] colprod = new IloLinearNumExpr[commuters];
            IloNumExpr[] firstpart = new IloLinearNumExpr[commuters];
            IloNumExpr[] finalobj = new IloLinearNumExpr[commuters];
            IloNumExpr[] obj = new IloLinearNumExpr[commuters];

            //1st part of objective
            for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<4;j++){
                firstpart[j] = cplex.prod(dr[i][j], z[i][j]);

                }
            }


            //2nd part of objective
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
                    cplex.sum(colexpr[j],1);
                }
                colexpr2[j] = cplex.sum(1,cplex.negative(colexpr[j]));
            }

            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                colprod[j] = cplex.prod(colexpr2[j],costs[j]);
            }

            //trying to merge 1st and 2nd part of objective function
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                finalobj[j]= cplex.sum(firstpart[j],colprod[j]);
            }


            for(int j=0; j<4;j++){
                //obj[j].addTerm(1.0,finalobj[j]);
                cplex.addMaximize(finalobj[j]);
            }
```

The part that confuses me more is how to pass in an expression the sum of the columns of arrays, and how to merge two expressions and pass it to cplex.addMaximize. Many times i get a compiler error ArrayStoreException because of IloNumVar and IlolinearNumVar.

Comment: Please give more information on what you have tried to do in order to solve this yourself.

Comment: Generally i want to merge many sub-expressions but i cannot.

Comment: Is the question still valid?